# Why is the name Mekom P'tur indicative of being entirely permissible?

Tags: shabbat, rambam, maseches-shabbos, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

In the introduction to Tractate Shabbat in his Commentary to the Mishnah, Rambam writes:

> אבל מקום פטור מותר להוציא ממנו לכל אחת משלש הרשיות ומהן אליו וזה מותר לכתחלה ולפיכך נקרא מקום פטור
>
> ([Kafih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Qafih) translation)
>
> But a *mekom p'tur* it is permissible to take out from it to any one of the [other] three domains, and from them to it, and this is permissible *ab initio* and therefore it is called "a place of exemption".
>
> (My translation)

Here Rambam tells us that the reason for the name *mekom p'tur* – place of exemption – is that carrying to and from that domain is entirely permissible. However, this seems to be a puzzling reason to give the domain this name. In the area of Shabbat, the term "exempt" (*patur*) usually carries the implication that the perpetrator is merely exempt, but *not* that the act is entirely permissible:

**[Shabbat 3a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=3&format=pdf)**

> והאמר שמואל כל פטורי דשבת פטור אבל אסור בר מהני תלת דפטור ומותר צידת צבי וצידת נחש ומפיס מורסא
>
> did not Samuel say: Everything [taught as] involving no liability on the Sabbath, involves [indeed] no liability, yet it is forbidden, save these three, which involve no liability and are [also] permitted: [viz.,] the capture of a deer,  the capture of a snake, and the manipulation of an abscess?
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_3.html))

Given that the connotation of "exempt" is expressly *not* "entirely permissible", why would this domain be named "a place of exemption" specifically to illustrate that it *is* entirely permissible?

Comment: Most Mekomot Petur are indeed rabbinically proscribed. See: "karmelit". Also many ways of carrying into a rabbinic Mekom Petur are proscribed (eg. to trick your way through a reshut harabbim). I don't know if the Rambam was thinking of these or not, but the fact is using a mekom petur lechatchila is virtually non existent in everyday life.

Comment: @DoubleAA Makom Petur and karmelis are  two entirely different categories.

Comment: @N.T. Why not just state what you want explicitly? Are you taking the position that there is a shem karmelit deorayta or are you disagreeing with the use of "makom ptur" to describe on a deorayta level everything that isn't rabbim or yachid?

Comment: @DoubleAA The latter. According to Rashi, Karmelis means a forest in Hebrew. According to Rambam, the word Karmelis means anything that does not fall into the Biblical category of rabbim or yachid, which is like a widow (כארמלית). Rabbinically, there are four reshuyos listed in the braisa: rabbim, yachid, karmelis, and makom p'tur.

Comment: @N.T. Shame, I was hoping for something more interesting than a word game. On a deorayta level, everything that you'd call "karmelit" and "makom ptur" are all just places where it's permitted to move things which, as noted in the quote in the question, is essentially what the name "makom ptur" is all about. Chazal placed certain restrictions on some of those places which we then call "karmelit" for whatever etymological reason you prefer.

Comment: what do you suggest they call it? מקום מותר??

Comment: @yih613 מקום היתר sounds plausible to me

Comment: @DoubleAA I think his question is very reasonable, though maybe your answer is the right one. While you are right on a d'oraysa level, pretty much everyone in the sources presents things as "four categories", one of which is מקום פטור. You're giving an interesting answer by saying that the name originates from the d'oraysa level where כרמלית is also part of it. Don't think it's the OP's fault if he hadn't approached it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The context leaves no doubt to indicate complete exemption as the use of *Petur* is relative to a Rabbinic enactment. The source of *Makom Petur* is Shabbos 7b which is talking about a specifically rabbinical forbidden to carry area called a *Carmelis*. Anything not within the parameters of a Rabbinic *Carmelis* is a place of rabbinic exemption (which means the rabbis had no concerns and allowed it) as there is no rabbinic enactment of *carmelis*

אין כרמלית למעלה מי' ואקילו בה רבנן מקולי רה"י ומקולי רה"ר מקולי רה"י דאי איכא מקום ארבעה הוא דהויא כרמלית ואי לא מקום פטור בעלמא הוא מקולי רה"ר דעד י' טפחים הוא דהויא כרמלי' למעלה מי' טפחים לא הויא כרמלי'

Shmuel (Shabbos 3a) is talking about non-indicative uses of *Patur* when refering to Petur as still being forbidden. He does not deny the word means "exempt" and could therefore mean exempt from Rabbinical prohibition (i.e permitted) if absolutetly clear from context.